# How can I create a game like Alias?

Tags: applications, code

I’m an ESL teacher in Russia. To engage my students more I really want to create a HTML5 game similar to Alias (see https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/alias-party-game/id1163843973?l=en).

I’m not a coder, so I’m looking for a code-free app creator resource that could be suitable for creating that type of games.

I’ve been looking on the Internet, but can’t find anything that could help.

Show me the way, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This StackExchange is not really the best place for this question. Nevertheless, there seem to already be a bunch of opensource projects already built emulating this game.

For example, you can look at [Aleks Hudochenkov's version](https://github.com/hudochenkov/alias-game). It lists words in English and Russian, and it looks like a great start. It requires [npm](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp) to build and [gulp](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) to run it, but this is how it looks like:

[image]

Another one, with a more polished look can be found in [Renato's GitHub](https://github.com/xdghcnt/alias-game-web). It only lists Croatian words, but it should not bee to difficult to modify it to fit your needs. It also displays a 60 seconds counter for every team, and tracks points:

[image]

[AndrewSergeev's Android version](https://github.com/AndrewSergeev/Alias-android-game) also looks amazing, and seems to 'emulate' the one you listed in your question. But it's written in Java, and would take quite the effort to start working on it.

And the ones I listed above are just a tiny fraction of open-source versions available for free, but they all require a bit of technical knowledge to get them working, and moderate levels of various programming languages proficiency (particularly JavaScript). My suggestion would be to look around on github for already built projects, and if you find something that's close to what you want, get in touch with the developer or fork the repository and start modifying it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! That’s what I’ve been looking for:)

Comment: Hey, glad I could help.